# Delete all elements with same value from doubly circular linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I have doubly circular linked list

```
struct Element {
    int data;
    Element *next;
    Element *previous;
};

struct List {
    Element *head;
};
```

The task is to delete elements/nodes with the same data. For example, if the list has 1,1,3,4,5,1 and after parsing the function value=1 it should be as following 3,4,5.

```
bool removeAllValue(List &l, int value) {
    if(!l.head)
        return false;
    else if(l.head->next == l.head && l.head->data == value){
        l.head = NULL;
        return true;
    }
    Element *p = l.head;
    do{
        if(p->data == value)
            removeElement(l, p);
        p = p->next;
    }while(p!=l.head);
    return true;
```

Above is function which itterates through elements, finds element with given value/data and calls the following function to delete element.

```
void removeElement(List &l, Element *element){
    Element *previous = element->previous;
    Element *next = element->next;
    Element *head = l.head;
    if(next == head){ //if element is tail of the list
        l.head->previous = element->previous; // relinking head's previous to new tail
        element->previous->next = head;
    }else if(element == head){ // if element is head of the list
        l.head = next; // relinking head to tail
        l.head->previous = previous; // relinking tail to head
    }else{
        previous->next = next;
        next->previous = previous;
    }
    delete element;

}
```

I have tried different ways but it always gave me errors. The problem is in relinking tail and head, as I think but I can't find the way to fix it.

Comment: The first case (element is the tail) seems odd. Why would you adjust head->next at all in this case? And why would tail's previous point to the head?

Comment: @MarekFekete Thanks. Changed it to following
`l.head->previous = element->previous;
element->previous->next = head;`

Comment: Looks better. Did it help?

Comment: @MarekFekete No, in case of list being 1,2,1,1 after the function it gives 2,1,1,0.

Comment: Another problem is that you do `delete element` in `removeElement`, and then still use it in the calling function afterwards (`p=p->next`).

Comment: @MarekFekete I changed it to this
`if(p->data == value){
            Element *tmp = p;
            p = p->next;
            removeElement(l, tmp);
        }else
            p = p->next;
`

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? `removeElement` logic should not depend on the position in the list, except when deleting the head element, but this case is a bit more involved than your code implies.

Comment: Another problem: when removing head, you are relinking new head's previous (which is the element being removed). You should instead be relinking the old head's previous to the new head (`head->previous=previous`).

Comment: And another problem - after removing head, your do-while condition in the calling function will trigger immediately, because the next element is the new head.

Comment: @MarekFekete I just fixed this by calling loop (that finds element and removes it) each time from the head after successful removal. The last problem I have is when the list consists only of same elements. It removes everything but the last element and assigns some random value (probably because of wrong pointer assignement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can streamline it. Handling the removing tail/head/middle situations in `removeElement` differently is not needed, with the only extra of resetting the list's head when removing the former head. I would rather put determining the next element in list and last item removal detection. Like this:

```
Element* removeElement(List &l, Element *element) {
    Element *newnext;
    Element *previous = element->previous;
    Element *next = element->next;
    Element *head = l.head;

    previous->next = next;
    next->previous = previous;
    newnext = next;

    if (element == head) { // if element is head of the list
        l.head = next; // set the head correctly
    }

    if (element == newnext)  // detect if last element in the list was deleted
        l.head = newnext = nullptr;
    else if (newnext == head) // detect if next is at the head again
        newnext = nullptr;

    delete element;
    return newnext;
}
```

Then you do not have to re-iterate from the head each tiem you remove an element and you do not have to handle the single item list as a special case:

```
bool removeAllValue(List &l, int value) {
    if (!l.head)
        return false;

    Element *p = l.head;
    do {
        if (p->data == value)
        {
            p = removeElement(l, p);
        }
        else
        {
            p = p->next;
            if (p == l.head)
                p = nullptr;
        }
    } while (p);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in few relinking operations

```
void removeElement(List &l, Element *element){
    Element *previous = element->previous;
    Element *next = element->next;
    Element *head = l.head;
    if(element->next == element)
        l.head = NULL;
    else if(next == head){ //if element is tail of the list
        Element *newTail = previous;
        newTail->next = l.head;
        l.head->previous = newTail;
    }else if(element == head){ // if element is head of the list
        l.head = next; // relinking head
        l.head->previous = previous; // relinking tail to head
        previous->next = l.head; // relinking head to tail
    }else{
        previous->next = next;
        next->previous = previous;
    }
    delete element;
}
```

And as Marek Fekete noticed I didn't change iterating pointer each time I deleted an element. So I just iterated through all list from the beginning, each time I deleted an element.

```
bool removeAllValue(List &l, int value) {
    if(!l.head)
        return false;
    else if(l.head->next == l.head && l.head->data == value){
        l.head = NULL;
        return true;
    }
    Element *p = l.head;
    bool end = false;
    while(!end){
        do{
            if(p->data == value){
                Element *tmp = p;
                p = p->next;
                removeElement(l, tmp);
                break;
            }else
                p = p->next;
            if(p==l.head || l.head == NULL){
                end = true;
                break;
            }
        }while(p);
    }
    return true;
}
```